# Sorting of data in Dropdown

Tags: c#-4.0, sorting, drop-down-menu

I want to sort my data which are bound to the dropdown.

I fetch the name of students from database but thought i can't directly use the orderby.

Because the data i get from the database is student id which is of Guid type.

Then i am finding the full name from the id.

Here's the code

```
public DataTable GetAllStudentNameFromMentor(Guid MentorId)
        {
            DataTable AllStudents = new DataTable();
            AllStudents.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(Guid));
            AllStudents.Columns.Add("studentName", typeof(string));
             var allm = from sm in Db.StudentMentor
                       where sm.MentorID.Equals(MentorId)
                       select sm;

            foreach (var v in allm)
            {
                string studentname = BussinesCollection.BussinesPerson.GetFullName(v.StudentID.Value);
                AllStudents.Rows.Add(v.StudentID,studentname);
            }
            return AllStudents;
        }
```

I am binding the table in dropdown.

```
ddlstudent.DataSource = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesMentor.GetAllStudentNameFromMentor(MentorID);
        ddlstudent.DataBind();
```

But I want the names should be in alphabetical order.

Would anyone like to help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can sort datatable using dataview as below :

1. First convert  the datatable to dataview and then sort

> DataView dataView = new DataView(AllStudents);
>
> ```
> dataView.Sort = "studentName ASC";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public DetaView GetAllStudentNameFromMentor(Guid MentorId)
{
  DataTable AllStudents = new DataTable();
  AllStudents.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(Guid));
  AllStudents.Columns.Add("studentName", typeof(string));
  var allm = from sm in Db.StudentMentor
             where sm.MentorID.Equals(MentorId)
             select sm; 
  foreach (var v in allm)
  {
      string studentname = BussinesCollection.BussinesPerson.GetFullName(v.StudentID.Value);
      AllStudents.Rows.Add(v.StudentID,studentname);
  }
AllStudents.DefaultView.Sort = "studentName ASC";
return AllStudents.DefaultView;
}
```

For more on this [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx)

Comment: which namespace will be needed for DafaultView? Because it shows error for namespace is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using id and value pair you could use a Dictionary which can be easily order. Also make sure to change the `ddl.DataValueField="Key"` and `ddl.DataTextField="Value"` on your markup or code behind before binding the dictionary to ddl.

```
public Dictionary<Guid, string> GetAllStudentNameFromMentor(Guid MentorId)
{
    Dictionary<Guid,string> myDic = new Dictionary<Guid,string>();

    var allm = from sm in Db.StudentMentor
                   where sm.MentorID.Equals(MentorId)
                   select sm;

    foreach (var v in allm)
    {
           myDic.Add(v.StudentID,
              BussinesCollection.BussinesPerson.GetFullName(v.StudentID.Value));
    }

    return myDic.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```